# Communication between two different tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code

```
$objectsLength = count($objects);
    for($i=0;$i<$objectsLength;$i++)
        {
           if($i == $o_id) {
               echo '<img src="'.$src; echo '"class="item" style="position:relative; left:'.$y; echo 'px; top:'.$x; echo 'px;">';   
            }
         }
```

This code looks in my database and sees if there are any `$o_id` equal to the `$i` value created just before the array. When it finds something equal to it; I need a value from another table in my MySQL database that has a id equal to `$i` or `$o_id` too. It is really hard to explain but I will need some code that does something like this:

```
if($i == $o_id) {
  Get 'src' value from table 'objects' which has the same 'id' as '$i'
  ... And so on. }
```

Uhm so I already got connection to the table that holds `src` and `id` so I wont need to establish a new connection. I just need a way for PHP to do the same thing as the line above. Any ideas? Anything is appreciated and thanks in advance. I know it must be hard to understand my problem but please ask further into it if you feel like.

Comment: so... put some fetch-from-DB logic or whatever it is you need inside that `$i == $o_id` block to do this.

Comment: provide bigger part of your code with sql query. For example as link to pastbin. Maybe it helps other to understand it better.

Comment: sql join? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Hint of dbames maybe very good one!

Comment: @MarcB that is exactly what I need but I have no idea how? Could you provide me with some information or a link to read further? Thanks

Comment: "this code looks in my database". You already have database code... why can't you write a bit more to run this other query? While we're happy to help, we're not here to help you with the basics.

Comment: @MarcB since I already have the variables holding the values from the database that I need, then I want to avoid to make another Database connection.. I just can't figure out how to write this in PHP. My head explodes :/

Comment: you don't need to make another db connection. one db connection can run as many queries as you want.

Comment: @MarcB but wouldn't another query cost more server activity rather than just reusing the variables that I already got once from another query? Or is it impossible to just say something like: PHP, get src where id was 2! Does that belong to a new database query instead?

Comment: if the tables are related, then use a `JOIN` query to fetch everything you need. If they're not related at all, then you'd have to run two queries anyways.